# Unable to get Riot.js observable to pass params via callback

Tags: javascript, observable, riot.js

My Riot.js observable is working as follows.

Inside my 'global-header' tag the riot.store observable in riot's global scope gets updated (the user enters a new height in input field) and then the observable triggers 'update_dims':

```
save_height() {
  riot.store.cardHeight = this.refs.input_card_height.value
  riot.store.trigger('update_dims')
}
```

Inside my 'card' tag the riot.store listens for 'update_dims' and succesfully updates { myCardHeight } in the interface.

```
// function updates the card height
update_cardHeight () {
  this.myCardHeight = riot.store.cardHeight
  this.update()
}
// observable runs when triggered and calls above function 'update_cardHeight'
riot.store.on('update_dims',this.update_cardDimensions)
```

However, if I try to pass parameters directly from riot.store.trigger:

```
save_height() {
  riot.store.cardHeight = this.refs.input_card_height.value
  riot.store.trigger('update_dims','450')
}
```

The observable below does not update the interface even though me.myCardHeight variable has been updated with the new height parameter:

```
me = this
riot.store.on('update_dims', function (height) {
  me.myCardHeight = height
  console.log(me.myCardHeight)
  me.update()
})
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your store is a riot observable this should work:

```
riot.store = riot.observable();

var me = this
riot.store.on('update_dims', function (height) {
  me.myCardHeight = height;
  console.log(me.myCardHeight);
  me.update();
});

riot.store.trigger('update_dims', 450);
```

If you're very interested in storing it in an object then I'd prefer to make a shared store with properties of it's own:

```
var store = {
  observable: riot.observable(),
  height: 25 // default
}

riot.mount('myCard', {store: store})
```

Then inside the tag `myCard`:

```
var me = this
me.myCardHeight = opts.store.height;

me.opts.store.on('update_dims', function (height) {
  me.opts.store.height = height;
  me.myCardHeight
  console.log(me.myCardHeight);
  me.update();
});
```

Now when you call this you'll be passing in a new shared height:

```
this.opts.trigger('update_dims', 450);
```

Also, check out [RiotControl](https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl) which can with this type of architecture.

Hope this helps!